# Can I control a cellphone's lcd (+touch screen)?

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

I had an Xperia txt pro just laying around and tried to revive it. I burned it like an idiot using 5v in the battery pins by accident :/
So I decided to read it apart and got to the lcd, can I use my Arduino Mega to control it? Bc I have no idea how to use it.

These are the pins[image: these are the pins]

Answer (score 3):

No. For two reasons:

1. You will struggle to find the pinout of the TFT (or even identify the model). It will have most likely been custom made for the phone.
2. The Arduino doesn't have a GPU to drive it. Arduinos need a TFT with built in GPU since they lack the resources to drive one directly.